# adding new UI Type in Vtiger 7.0

Tags: php, vtigercrm

I have tried to create a new UI Type in vtiger 7.0.0. but facing the below error.
"Unable to load template file 'modules/Vtiger/uitypes/**Questionnaire.tpl**' in 'modules/Vtiger/partials/**EditViewContents.tpl**'"

Steps which I have followed to create a new UI Type are as below.

Step1: update "**modules\Vtiger\models\Field.php**" and add new UIType as 222

Step2: created a new file "**modules\Vtiger\uitypes\Questionnaire.php**"

Step3: created new .tpl files "**layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\uitypes\Questionnaire.tpl**" and "**QuestionnaireFieldSearchView.tpl**" in the same dir.

after all these steps facing the above issue.

any help/guidance will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this, steps are as below.

Step1: update "modules\Vtiger\models\Field.php" and add new UIType as 222

Step2: created a new file "modules\Vtiger\uitypes\Questionnaire.php"

Step3: created new .tpl files "layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\uitypes\Questionnaire.tpl" and "QuestionnaireFieldSearchView.tpl" in the same dir.

Step4: created new .tpl files "layouts\v7\modules\Vtiger\uitypes\Questionnaire.tpl" and "QuestionnaireFieldSearchView.tpl" in the same dir.

Step5: Register/insert new UIType in table **vtiger_ws_fieldtype**

Thats all i need to create new UIType