# Custom Field in Vtiger 7

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Im trying to create a custom UIType and a followed [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362965/adding-new-ui-type-in-vtiger-7-0/55192520#55192520) without success, this is what i did:

Step1: update "modules\Vtiger\models\Field.php" and add new UIType as 222

I added the new UIType as follow in Field.php into public function getFieldDataType()

```
} else if($uiType == '222') {
            $fieldDataType = 'json';
```

Step5: Register/insert new UIType in table vtiger_ws_fieldtype

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbX09.png)

But doesn't work

Comment: Did you create tpl, php file for new data type?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create new uitype just to store json then no need to create new uitype for it. You can create [new text field](https://discussions.vtiger.com/discussion/177614/add-custom-field-to-users-module) to store json value in database

- use `json_encode` to store json in newly created text field
- use `json_decode` while fetching the value from db and use whenever needed.

And if you still want to create new uitype then you can follow the description and steps given [here](https://discussions.vtiger.com/discussion/56353/how-to-create-a-new-ui-type-in-vtiger-6)